# Como adicionar a licença WTFPL ao meu projeto?

Tags: licença

Possuo um projeto que terá livre distribuição, alteração, cópia e o que mais surgir, e vi que existe a licença [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) que funciona dessa forma.

Em seu site temos o [modelo do texto](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/) a ser inserido no projeto, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
 DO WHAT THE FU** YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
                    Version 2, December 2004 

 Copyright (C) 2004 Sam Hocevar <sam@hocevar.net> 

 Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim or modified 
 copies of this license document, and changing it is allowed as long 
 as the name is changed. 

            DO WHAT THE FU** YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
   TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR COPYING, DISTRIBUTION AND MODIFICATION 

  0. You just DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO.
```

A minha dúvida é: **Devo alterar a data, nome e e-mail do texto ou deixar da mesma forma?**

Faço essa pergunta, pois se olharmos o [Showcase](http://www.wtfpl.net/showcase/), podemos ver vários exemplos com o texto igual, mas também alguns com a alteração nos dados, por isso essa dúvida.

Comment: Lembrando que o `FU**` foi adicionado manualmente por que acho que não seria adequado colocar a palavra correta no site, especialmente por questão de aparecer nas buscas. Porém, na licença não tem os "asteriscos".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nenhuma fonte é melhor do que o site oficial da licença, então vamos ver o que ele diz sobre isso.

Na [página de FAQ](http://www.wtfpl.net/faq/) da licença, possuímos um "pequeno" tutorial de como adicionar a licença em seu projeto, que segue dois passos:

1º Tenha uma cópia original do arquivo em sue projeto ou referencie o arquivo do site oficial, ou seja, com os dados mostrado da licença: **[...] 2004 Sam Hocevar < sam@hocevar.net>[...]**. Normalmente o arquivo tem o nome de **COPYING.WTFPL**.

2º Adicione as declarações do ano e do autor em seu projeto.

```
Copyright © 2000 Your Name <your@address>
This work is free. You can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
terms of the Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License, Version 2,
as published by Sam Hocevar. See the COPYING file for more details.
```

Se por algum motivo o projeto não possua o arquivo, referencia desta forma:

```
Copyright © 2000 Your Name <your@address>
This work is free. You can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
terms of the Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License, Version 2,
as published by Sam Hocevar. See http://www.wtfpl.net/ for more details.
```

Em resumo, você deverá ter os dois em seu projeto ou referenciar o site da licença.

Talvez essa imagem explique melhor:

[image: Descrição da licença]

Para exemplificar melhor, [este projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/Logga) possui um exemplo de utilização da licença.

Para maiores informações, veja o [próprio site da licença.](http://www.wtfpl.net/faq/)

Answer (score 3):

Claro que se isto é realmente muito importante deve procurar um advogado.

Se posso dar um conselho, eu usaria uma licença que mais (re)conhecida e provavelmente mais "séria". Não vejo uma vantagem de usar esta. Eu prefiro até um *public domain* explícito, se for o caso, ainda que esta não seja uma boa licença do ponto de vista legal, do que uma deste tipo.

No meu entendimento é para personalizar com seus dados (exceto a data do texto da licença em si). É assim nas licenças mais óbvias:

- [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
- [Apache](https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0)
- [BSD](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)
- [Artistic](https://opensource.org/licenses/Artistic-2.0)

Com a resposta do Randrade vejo um motivo a mais para não usar esta licença. Ela é confusa, induz a erro, precisa ir atrás da documentação dela para saber o que aquilo quer dizer, o oposto do que ela tenta "vender".

Comment: Isso da data do texto o qual citou é valido no MIT também, eu uso muito ele todos casos que vi as pessoas editam a data do MIT para o ano que o script/biblioteca/etc foi escrito.

Comment: Agradeço a sua opinião, e ela é muito bem vinda. Mas eu queria saber realmente sobre a licença, pois no site dela não deixa muito claro. Os showcases ainda são piores, pois alguns usam o padrão da pergunta e outros editam os dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A data da licença sim, o MIT não tem data do texto.

Comment: @Randrade você só terá algo melhor que isto perguntado para o autor ou para um advogado especializado. Talvez seja o caso de fechar a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown Já achei a resposta, irie publicar aqui, 1 min.

Comment: Agora acesse o tinha me esquecido, o exemplo segue assim: `Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>`, então o ano é "customizado" mesmo e apache `Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]`

Comment: Adicionei a resposta retirada do próprio site.